# Repository of My Academic Writing - Which License to Use?

Tags: technical-writing, academic-writing, legal

I'm adding a repository containing selected academic papers I wrote.  I'd like to add a license to this repository that works similarly to the MIT license (but for writing and not code), where others could fork and use my writing, but must include attribution back to me somewhere.  At the same time, I wan't to be able to accept pull requests, if anyone sees an error in my writing and wants to fix it.  I'm not very versed in licenses and this side of the law, so any suggestions would be great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have a look to the [Creative Commons website](https://creativecommons.org). They have [a tool to help you choose the most convenient license for your works](https://creativecommons.org/choose/). In your case, I think the best one is the [BY-NC-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/), which allows to fork but requires attribution and forbids commercial uses.

Regarding the pull requests, it is another problem. The first idea that comes to my mind is to use a code repository like [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/explore) which is free as in speech or [Github](https://github.com/). They will also allowed other people to fork your works a proper way.

Comment: Yes.  I’m a computer science major and have been using GitHub for years and have a GitHub account.  The only reason I’m committing my academic writing to a GitHub repository would be to showcase the writing side to potential future explorers.  I knew of Creative Commons, but didn’t know of the tool to help decide what license to use.  Thank you.